# Discord bot not responding to command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to code the bot to generate a random percentage when the command !percent is used while also mentioning the user. When I use the command it doesn't seem to work but no errors pop up in the console.

```js
if (message.content == ("!Percent" || message.content == "!percent")) {
        if (message.isMemberMentioned()) { 
            message.isMemberMentioned.users.forEach((k, v) => { 
                message.channel.send( v + ' is ' + ( Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 ) + "%  ! " );
          })
        }
      }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '!percent'){...
```

or..

```js
if(['!Percent', '!percent'].includes(message.content)){...
```

Not

```js
if (message.content == ("!Percent" || message.content == "!percent")) {...
```

Is wrong as its comparing message content, a string, to a boolean as "!Percent" will always be true.

The `Message` class doesn't have a `#isMemberMentioned` method documented (never existed??) if you want support for that edit your post with the function code. Same goes for the `isMemberMentioned` property on the `Message` class variable.

Comment: The 3rd one won't work, it will only check `!Percent` because it's truthy and it only checks `message.content === "!Percent"`

Comment: Thats the code they were using, I explained why its wrong in the line under. Edited answer to better reflect this.